# Use MKMapView's showShowsUserLocation method without displaying the view

Tags: ios

As you may know, locating using CLLocationManager is inaccurate in China. However, Apple includes a shift function in MKMapView so the coordinate taken from it is correct.

Now I want to use purely MKMapView's locating feature to get current location. Following is my code:

In my LocationManager's init function:

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

In mapView's delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    NSLog(@"%@", userLocation.location);
}
```

Now the problem comes. If I do NOT add the mapView to the rootViewControler's view, nothing happens and the mapView will NOT perform locating, i.e. I have to call the following code:

```
[self.view addSubview:[FTLocationManager sharedManager].mapView];
```

in the [viewDidLoad:] method of my root view controller to let mapView to work.

I tried to create a UIViewController programmatically and add mapView to its view, but still nothing happens.

I guess MKMapView will only start locating current user when it is displayed on screen.

Is there a way to trigger MKMapView to start locating current location without showing it on screen?

Comment: Did u check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your mapView to some view, if you don't want to show it on screen. See my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:aView.bounds];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [aView addSubview:_mapView];

}
```

Above code will add mapView, but delegate method `didUpdateUserLocation:` will not be called if you are testing on simulator, since user location has not been simulated.

For this, attach a breakpoint and simulate some location to trigger call to delegate function.

[image]

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I know this method. But it requires to present this view controller. I tested on my iPhone. As long as the view controller is presented will the mapView start to locate. What I want is to run KMMapView completely off screen, and do not add it to any views.

Comment: @HanXu The view `aView` has been never added to main view. So it is completely off-screen and safe for you. Moreover, you have to add map to some view in order to trigger its methods.